# Is it possible to receive reputation points on meta?

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta

Is it possible to receive reputation points on meta? I have asked 1 question, which got upvoted, but before asking it I had 101 reputations. After the upvote I still see 101 reputations. I know that every upvote gives you another 5 reputations, so I should have 106 reputations, but not 101.

Is this a bug that I should report it?